# Permanantly delete BITS annd Windows update services in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have windows 10 enterprizes. i know that there is no way to stop windows 10 update. but we can only stop it from downloading updates by using registry and group policy. but it still takes too much of internet to check for updates
on my computer i don`t want to update it because i use  WUD to update it. actually i want to delete these services so that neither windows update nor any other app can use internet through BITS. any way to delete it. i had tried soloutions to disable it but after some time they automaticaly start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BITS and Windows update services can be disabled by deleting their associated .dll files.

Here's how:

1. Open services through Task manager
2. Find the BITS and wuauserv services and disable them
3. Open `windows\system32\`
4. Find `qmgr.dll` and `wuaueng.dll`
5. Take ownership of these files using properties and  move these files to another disk

Now those services will never run.

If you want to enable them again, transfer the .dll files back to the `system32` folder.

**Note**: In case you lose these files you cannot use dll files from another version of windows like windows 7 or 8. Instead you will have to repair the windows on the computer or reinstall it.

Comment: Together with this: https://www.aqtronix.com/?PageID=96

Comment: I hope this way we can kick that a**.