# Disable Background Intelligent Transfer Service

Tags: windows-10, services

I try to Disable **Background Intelligent Transfer Service** in win 10 but after restart my computer rerun and start for download .
I disable this service in **services** of windows. I first right click on the service name and choose **stop** and then right click on the service name and choose **properties** under general tab select **StartUp Type : Disabled**.

How can I prevent of rerun this service in start of computer?
[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to stop the service? like the other core windows 10 services, BITS is only active when called by another service. It is primarily used by the update service, but others call it as well. rather than blocking the helper what you need to block is the active service that uses it.

Comment: This service download 2000 MB in two day .I do not need to use this features

Comment: That is what I was trying to explain the BITS service schedules and manages large transfers for other applications.  It runs the transfers when your network is at low utilization.  You need to change the settings for the service or application which called BITS and requested the download.

Comment: Did you try this workaround - https://superuser.com/a/1592658?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanantly delete BITS annd Windows update services in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1058487/permanantly-delete-bits-annd-windows-update-services-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have control over windows services as you used to. 
Windows 10 can start any services and re-enable any features at any time without any notifications. And it does that, specially when updates are applied.

You can remove some services (like ASP.NET State Service or Application Host Helper Service) by using the Turn Windows Features On or Off feature, but the main windows ones you cannot actually control.

The only way to make sure the services you want are disabled is to make a batch file that runs at startup and disabled them every time.

```
sc config "NameOfService" start= disabled
sc stop "NameOfService"
```

Note: that space after "=" must be there.

Comment: I wrote a text file with sc config "BITS" start= disabled
sc config "wuauserv" start= disabled statements and save as .bat file . Now When I run as administrator this file disable my windows updates .

Comment: Of course you should save this file in a drive then add shortcut of this file to the windows startup and set run as administrator for this shortcut.This worked currently for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and then I came to find that it can't be stopped permanently as per the info on this website guide :

https://www.techwibe.com/bits-bandwidth-eating-windows-10-fix-or-solution-for-laptop-and-pc/

> Why this service keeps on restarting after restarting my PC or laptop?
>
> This is an important component that keeps Win10 running smoothly so even if you disable or stop it, it will restart. Major factor that triggers is the Windows 10 OS update and you need to disable Win10 auto updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable BITS permanently as windows enable it automatically after few days.
But you can set bandwidth consumption of BITS to 0kbps and restrict it from eating up internet speed.

This is the only trick I found to control BITS and it worked perfectly for me.
So here you go,

1. Open start menu(or press windows key), type gpedit.msc(Edit group Policy) and open it.
2. Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS)
3. Edit(double click) **Limit the maximum network bandwidth for BITS background transfers.**
4. Now select **Enable** and change **Limit background transfer rate(kbps) to** to 0 or some lower value like 2. Remember you need to set this at 2 places on same screen, one for scheduled time and one for all other times.

That's it. BITS will now use only the bandwidth you have specified.